# How to get non transparant nice flags in TYPO3 language menu

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a Language menu working in a TYPO3 9.5.* system. It works ok. Only the flags shown are not so nice. How can I get this looking better (on a dark background).

This is the TS:

```
lib.language.20 >
lib.language.20 = HMENU
lib.language.20 {
   special = language
   special.value = 3,2,0
   special.normalWhenNoLanguage = 0

   1 = GMENU
   1.NO {
       XY = [5.w]+16, [5.h]+16
       transparentBackground=1
       5 = IMAGE
       5.file = /typo3conf/ext/shufflemix_template_new/Resources/Public/images/flags/de.png  || /typo3conf/ext/shufflemix_template_new/Resources/Public/images/flags/en.png  || /typo3conf/ext/shufflemix_template_new/Resources/Public/images/flags/nl.png
       5.offset = 2,2
   }
   1.ACT < .1.NO
   1.ACT = 1
   1.ACT.transparentBackground=0 

   1.USERDEF1 < .1.NO
   1.USERDEF1 = 1
   1.USERDEF1.transparentBackground=0
   1.USERDEF1.10 = EFFECT
   1.USERDEF1.10.value = #223965
   1.USERDEF1.noLink = 1

   1.USERDEF2 < .1.USERDEF1
   1.USERDEF2.transparentBackground=0
}
```

The menu looks fine on a white background. But on a dark background the transparency and gifbuilder creates a problem. Parts of the flag are invisible or the flag gets a white background which is bigger than the flag itself.
What to change to get nice looking flags :) ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have only GIFs as resulting images.
GIF suffer from a very small Palette and that transparency is defined just for single pixel. Any colour or transparency gradients are dithered with pixel of transparency or not and only one colour from the small palette.
Go to your `Image processing configuration`  (not `Configuration Presets`but `Configure Installation-Wide Options`) and look for `[GFX][gdlib_png]`. This should be active, so your resulting images should be PNG which are capable of alpha-transparency.

Otherwise: make sure your images are not scaled for display. Scaling images in the browser also might result in unwanted artefacts.

Comment: I went for an other solution using the LanguageMenuProcessor to build a language menu using the core icons instead. Have that working and the result is what I needed. Indeed with png. Thanks for your input :)